# Service Account Unable to Interact with GKE Cluster in Another Project

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, google-iam

A service account (`$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A`) from one Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project (`$PROJECT_A`) is **unable** to interact with a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster (`$GKE_CLUSTER_B`) within another GCP project (`$PROJECT_B`); where:

- `$PROJECT_A` is the name of the project `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A` lives within
- `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A` is of the form `some-name@some-project-name@.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- `$PROJECT_B` is the name of the project the `$GKE_CLUSTER_B` cluster lives within
- `$GKE_CLUSTER_B` is a GKE cluster name, **not** context, of the form: `some_cluster`

`$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A` is unable to interact with a `$GKE_CLUSTER_B` **despite** possessing roles from `$PROJECT_B` containing permissions that should allow it to do so.

I.e., first I created a *custom* role `$ROLE`:

```sh
gcloud iam roles create $ROLE \
--description="$ROLE_DESCRIPTION" \
--permissions=container.clusters.get,container.clusters.list \
--project=$PROJECT_B \
--title='$ROLE_TITLE'

#=>

Created role [$ROLE].
description: $ROLE_DESCRIPTION
etag: . . .
includedPermissions:
- container.clusters.get
- container.clusters.list
name: projects/$PROJECT_B/roles/$ROLE
stage: . . .
title: $ROLE_TITLE
```

then I associated `$ROLE`, from `$PROJECT_B`, with `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A`:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_B \
--member=serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A \
--role=projects/$PROJECT_B/roles/$ROLE

#=>

Updated IAM policy for project [$PROJECT_B].
auditConfigs:
. . .
```

and I am able to see `$ROLE` under `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A`:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_B \
--flatten='bindings[].members' \
--format='value(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A}"

#=>

projects/$PROJECT_B/roles/$ROLE
```

with the proper permissions:

```sh
gcloud iam roles describe $ROLE \
--flatten='includedPermissions' \
--format='value(includedPermissions)' \
--project=$PROJECT_B

#=>

container.clusters.get
container.clusters.list
```

but still unable to get `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A` to interact with `$GKE_CLUSTER_B`.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the Kubernetes Engine API (found [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview)) for `$PROJECT_A`, even if `$PROJECT_A` doesn't have or need a GKE cluster.

You can confirm this by creating a new JSON key for `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A`:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create \
./some-key.json \
--iam-account="${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A}" \
--key-file-type="json"

#=>

created key [$KEY_ID] of type [json] as [./some-key.json] for [$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A]
```

activate the service account:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account \
"${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A}" \
--key-file=./some-key.json

#=>

Activated service account credentials for: [$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A]
```

confirm it's active:

```sh
cloud auth list
                        Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        . . .
*       $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A
        your@account.user
        . . .

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

and attempt to interact with `$GKE_CLUSTER_B`:

```sh
gcloud container clusters list --project=$PROJECT_B

#=>

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.list) ResponseError: code=403, message=Kubernetes Engine API has not
been used in project $PROJECT_A_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview?project=$PROJECT_A_ID
then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our
systems and retry.
```

where `$PROJECT_A_ID` is a numeric id of the form: `xxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Visit the address returned along with the `403` above ([here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/container.googleapis.com/overview)) and enable the Kubernetes Engine API.  `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_A` *should* now be able to interact with GKE clusters within `$PROJECT_B`:

```sh
gcloud container clusters list \
--project=$PROJECT_B \
--format='value(name)

#=>

. . .
some_cluster
. . .
```

including `$GKE_CLUSTER_B`.